# How to get time in current time zone from ISO 8601 strings?

Tags: java, date, iso

In my sqlite database I have a table with a field `created_at` that stores time in ISO8601 as `text`. In the object corresponding to this table I have two fields `String date, String time` for the `created_at` attribute. Now, while querying for this table and creating a corresponding object I am stuck at converting the ISO8601 string to the current user's timezone's date (YYYY/MM/DD), time (XX:YY pm). Could anyone help me out? I thought of using substring to split the string but then the timezone is UTC for ISO8601 strings.

The ISO8601 string is stored in the database using Instant.now().toString()

**tldr:** created_at = ISO8601 time string; need to extract date and time portion from it for the current user.

Comment: @user16320675 Instant.now().toString();

Comment: like `"2022-04-07T21:07:26.961524500Z"`? so just `Instant.parse(text)` and then `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant()` with the desired `ZoneId` (e.g. `TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()`)

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) comes in many variants. Please paste an example or two of what you have got.

Comment: @learner *why is it being downvoted?* I didn’t downvote either. My guess is it’s for lack of demonstration of a search and research effort on your part. It’s better to tell us what your search brought up and specify in what way it was insufficient for reaching your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Read the Wikipedia page on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

## *java.time*

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Generate ISO 8601 string.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

The `Z` on the end of that resulting string means an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Adjust into a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Unfortunately, the ISO 8601 standard does not define a format for a moment as seen in a time zone. The `ZonedDateTime#toString` method uses a format similar to ISO 8601 but appends the name of the time zone in square brackets. This is a smart solution.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

Much of your Question in not clear. I am guessing you want to pull the date and time portions from a `ZonedDateTime`. But I am not sure using such values to query your database makes sense. But if you insist:

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

You can get an ISO 8601 string for each.

```
String ldOutput = ld.toString() ;
String ltOutput = lt.toString() ;
```

Notice there is no need for the string manipulations you mentioned in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can see [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) you might find some answers.

But for example, you can see this example here. I have a String format and I transform it into a Date object.

```java
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String string1 = "2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700";
Date result1 = df1.parse(string1);
```

Comment: isn't it in UTC? I need in the user's timezone.

Comment: that format is iso8601

Comment: Please don't use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, as they are outdated. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.